# MySQL to Microsoft SQL Server derived table syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am trying to select data from a derived table created in the FROM statement.
I have the following code in MySQL:

```
SELECT  TEMP.State, TEMP.Name

FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT STATE.State, PRODUCT.Name, PRODUCT.Price
        FROM STATE
        JOIN PRODUCT) AS TEMP
```

I'm trying to do the same in Microsoft SQL Server, but this doesn't work, with an error 'incorrect syntax'. I've tried a few different combinations, and anything I can find says this should work.
All help appreciated!

Comment: In SQL Server when you join, you need to join "ON" something.

Comment: Missing join condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current MySQL subquery appears to be a *cross join*, as it is an inner join without any `ON` clause.  SQL Server does not support this syntax, and if you really want to use a cross join here, then use:

```
SELECT
    TEMP.State,
    TEMP.Name
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT STATE.State, PRODUCT.Name, PRODUCT.Price
    FROM STATE
    CROSS JOIN PRODUCT
) AS TEMP;
```

This being said, I see no reason for the subquery on either database, just use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.State, p.Name
FROM STATE s
CROSS JOIN PRODUCT p;
```